# Change the key used for displaying the Menu Bar, or disable it (or possibly stop window manager sending `alt`)

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, kde-plasma-5

I use Firefox on linux and one of the things I like about it is using <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>drag</kbd> to move windows around (and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>right-click-drag</kbd> to resize).
However, this causes the Menu Bar to open, which is annoying and requires me to hit <kbd>alt</kbd> again to dismiss it before the page responds to typing.
<sub>(I don't want the bar to always be open either).</sub>

[image] [image]

Is there a way to get Firefox to listen to a different key to open the Menu Bar, or even disabling it outright (the hamburger menu does have most things)?
Possibly something in `about:config` I haven't found?

**Edit:** I just noticed it happens after I've finished the drag and released the <kbd>alt</kbd> key. Should X/Plasma (I don't know who's responsible) even be sending an `alt-up` event to the window if it knows I had just been using it as a window manipulation shortcut-key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `ui.key.menuAccessKeyFocuses`. Set it to `false` and the menu bar won't pop up unless you hit one of its accelerators (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for "File").

Comment: thanks for that! I also noticed that the other key, `ui.key.menuAccessKey`, has a value of `18`; the keycode for <kbd>alt</kbd>. So, for posterity, if anyone wants to change the key (as per question title) you can do so here knowing the keycode